# iPhone NSString problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I'm using a var current_query to keep track of urls to load in my app. When I spec current_query with a static type string, i.e. `current_query = @"hey"`; It works to be expected, but when I start using dynamic values, such as.. `current_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey%@",hey2];` I get weird results.. When I `NSLog(@"%@",current_query);`, I also get weird results like `<1002f2c8 c0a8016a 00000000 00000000>` Is it converting my string somehow? Whats going on here?

current_query is in my header file as `NSString *current_query;` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *current_query;` and then in my implementation file with `@synthesize current_query;`

Thanks all!

Comment: What is hey2? Seems it is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the property instead of setting the instance variable directly:

```
self.current_query = NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey%@",hey2];
```

(Aside: `currentQuery` is the standard Obj-C naming convention.)

Answer (score -1):

Try fully allocating current_query first.
NSString current_query = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hey"];
current_query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hey%@", hey2];
NSLog(@"%@", current_query);

also if hey2 is not an object and is instead a primitive like int, you cannot use %@. you have to use the appropriate string token.